# NAND logical bitwise operation in ARM

Tags: assembly, arm, bitwise-operators, arm7

Is there a way to perform a bitwise NAND operation on the bits in two registers in ARM7, either with the existing AND, OR and EOR operations or other instructions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure; AND the two registers and then EOR the result with all 1's (for the negation).

Comment: Note that `eor r0, #-1` is not encodeable; you'd need the all-ones constant in a register.  That's what makes `mvn` a better choice.

Answer (score 8):

`and` then `mvn` ([move not](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0204j/Cihcdbca.html)).

From [GCC explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22:3,%22filterAsm%22%3a%7B%22labels%22%3atrue,%22directives%22%3atrue,%22commentOnly%22%3atrue%7D,%22compilers%22%3a%5B%7B%22source%22%3a%22int%20nand%28int%20a,%20int%20b%29%20%7B%5Cn%5Ctreturn%20~%28a%20&%20b%29;%5Cn%7D%5Cn%22,%22compiler%22%3a%22/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-g++-4.6%22,%22options%22%3a%22-O2%22%7D%5D%7D)

```
int nand(int a, int b) {
    return ~(a & b);
}

nand(int, int):
    and r0, r0, r1
    mvn r0, r0
    bx  lr
```